# Stream video using cloudfront and ffmpeg only

Tags: video, ffmpeg, amazon-cloudfront

I'm new to web streaming and was doing some experiments. I was wondering if it is possible stream video using ffmpeg and AWS Cloudfront. I've following things in place:

```
1. Cloudfront http and rtmp instance
2. Ubuntu as OS
3. A foscam ip camera at http://xxx.xxxx.net:9002 which can be accessed using url http://xxx.xxxx.net:9002/videostream.cgi?user=xxxx&password=xxxx
4. jwplayer
```

I used following using ffmpeg to stream data using cloudfront:

```
ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i 'http://xxx.xxx.net:9002/videostream.cgi?user=xxx&pwd=xxxx'  -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -preset veryfast -minrate 150k -maxrate 500k -s 960x540 -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 96000 -threads 0 -f flv - | tee name.flv | ffmpeg -i - -codec copy -f flv -metadata streamName=livestream rtmp://xxxxx.cloudfront.net/
```

To test the ffmpeg command above, I setup a crtmpserver on local machine and replaced rtmp://xxxxx.cloudfront.net/ with tcp://0.0.0.0:6666. This worked fine and I could view the live stream on jwplayer once I specified the crtmpserver url for jwplayer.

So, if it is possible, I need to do the following in descending order of preference:

```
1. Stream video directly to cloudfront and access it using jwplayer using ffmpeg.
2. Save video to S3 bucket using ffmpeg.
```

From documentations, streaming can be done using Adobe media server, Wowza etc. I was just wondering if this can be achieved using ffmpeg and cloudfront only.

Comment: You can use the [tee muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee) to stream and save a file at the same time. Also see [Creating Multiple Outputs with `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs).